# How to allow the REST call in Spring only for the user modifying itself?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have

```
@PutMapping("/users/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public User updateUser(@PathVariable("id") Long userId, @RequestBody User updatedUser){
...
}
```

I know I can use @PreAuthorize to protect the method depending on what role you are. But I want to only allow this API call for the user editing himself only. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `@PreAuthorize` , you can use SpEL to access the property of the input argument . It also provides a built-in expression `authentication` to access the `Authentication` instance (and a shortcut `principal` to access `Authentication.getPrincipal()` ) from the current `SecurityContext`.

For the default JDBC authentication , the principal is that `UserDetails` instance which does not store the user id. So I suggest you to customize it to include the user ID . After that , you could do something like :

```java
@PutMapping("/users/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
@PreAuthorize("#updatedUser.userId == principal.userId")
public User updateUser(@PathVariable("id") Long userId, @RequestBody User updatedUser){

}
```

Comment: This is the answer thanks. I have no idea why I keep getting downvoted for my questions?

Comment: i am also not sure. seems that some guy downvote your question and i have no idea why he downvote ....